# Original filetype of ashx file

Tags: ashx

I'm building a PHP application that uses data from a web service. I add an image to a desktop application which then saves it to the web. The web service provides image URLs using the `.ashx` file extension. If I put one of these in an `<img src="file.ashx?pictureId=abc123">`, it displays as an image.

I want to store these images. I know they'll generally be `.jpg` files and can run `file_get_contents` on this and save it as such. However, if one was a `.png`, for example, I'd still be saving it with a `.jpg` extension, so it's an assumption I don't wish to make.

I've had a look at the raw string of characters of the file and cannot see any identifying features to tell me that it's a `.jpg`, apart from perhaps the clue that it was created in Photoshop. Nowhere does it say what kind of file it was originally, either extension or original filename.

Is there a way of finding the original filetype of a file contained within `.ashx` URL?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make any sense. Maybe the `.ashx` script generates the image on the fly out of nothing and there is no "original".

The correct question is: how to find the type of the image retrieved from the `.ashx` URL?

Save the image into a (temporary) file then use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to find its type (GIF, JPEG, PNG etc) and choose the correct termination for its final file name.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give that a go. Sorry for it not making any sense - I've never come across this file extension before beginning this project,